# Filename include slash punctuation and gives Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: foo/boo/en_en.json (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, scala, file, macos-sierra, slash

I am trying to create a new file as a **boo/en_en.json** to foo folder, but IntelliJ Idea thinks that **boo** is a directory and **en_en.json** is a file. How should I fix that problem?

My code is:

```
val target = new PrintWriter(new File(s"foo/$name-$locale.json"))
```

And name includes slash punctuation.

Operating system is MacOs Sierra.

Comment: Well, `/` *is* the file separator on MacOs as far as I know, isn't it? Can you even create a file with this name by other means?

Comment: Why would you even think about using forward slash in file name?

Comment: Hello @Hulk  It is requirement of project. I can create a file manually on my computer but I cannot with that code.

Comment: Hello @Dummy same answer above. Check please

Comment: @Hulk Sorry I added scala to tags. I used Java library in scala.

Answer (score 1):

Its not intellij that blocking it, you cant put slash in your file names underlying api is blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to create a file with a `/` in it's name on OSX through the java api.  You can manually do this in the finder, but it's silently replacing the `/` with a `:` in the file name it actually saves to disk.  If you want it to appear in finder as a `/`, then save it with a `:`.  Any programs that access the file will have to refer to it with the `:`

[image: example of filename on commandline vs in finder]

This is due to differences between legacy mac file system paths and unix filesystem paths.

However, it's a **terrible** idea to ever have a `/` in a filename, since it is incredibly confusing.